# Numerical polynomials by means of prime powers

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, rational-numbers

Let $\mathbb{E}$ be the set of prime powers (except $1$). Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a rational polynomial with $f(\mathbb{E}) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. Does it follow that $f$ is numerical, i.e. satisfies $f(\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$?

Notice that the set $\mathbb{P}$ of prime numbers is not enough, as the example $(x^3+x+2)/4$ shows.

*Example.* If $q$ is a prime power, then $(q^{10}-q^{5}-q^2+q)/10$ is the number of monic irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of degree $10$. Can we conclude from this directly that $(q^{10}-q^{5}-q^2+q)/10$ is an integer, for every integer $q$ (which I also know to be true for other reasons)?

Comment: I don't know but I would start on this as follows. Let $m$ be the lcm of the denominators of the coefficients of $f$. Multiplying everything by $m$ you are then asking whether for a polynomial with integer coefficients $f(n)\equiv0\pmod m$ for all integers $n$ is equivalent to requiring the same for all $n\in\Bbb{E}$. The reason why this approach might give an answer is that, given an $m$, the ideal of polynomials vanishing modulo $m$ is completely understood. I needed to search this once. Niven & Warren published a solution in the 50's and Singmaster in the 60's.

Comment: (cont'd) A paper by Carlitz says that this (in the special case of a prime power $m$) was an exercise in a book by Dickson from 1910s :-) Anyway, the characterization of the ideal $I_m$ polynomials $g(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ such that they vanish modulo $m$ everywhere is the following. Consider the descending factorials $g_j(x)=x(x-1)\cdots (x-j+1)$. The values of $g_j(x)$ are all multiples of $j!$. So if $d(j,m)$ is the smallest integer such that $m\mid d(j,m) j!$ then $d(j,m)g_j(x)\in I_m$. And such polynomials generate the ideal $I_m$.

Comment: (cont'd) This generating set of $I_m$ is not minimal. For example when $m=p^t$ for some prime $p$, you only need as generators the polynomials $d(j,m)g_j(x)$ such that $p\mid j$. And once $j$ is large enough that $p^t\mid j!$ you can stop. Not sure to that this will lead to an answer, but it does feel promising. As always, the Chinese remainder theorem is your friend when extending from a prime powers to the general case.

Comment: Thank you! By coincidence, I was also asking myself how to describe this ideal recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The polynomial $p(x)=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-7)}{4}$ takes integer values with $p(x) \equiv 0 \bmod 8$ for all $x \not\equiv 6 \bmod 8$, but $p(6) \equiv 4 \bmod 8$. If $x$ is a prime power, then $x \not\equiv 6 \bmod 8$. It follows that $\frac{p(x)}{8}$ takes integer values at all prime powers, but not at $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Following Jyrki Lahtonen's suggestion, let's write $f(x)=xg(x)+t$ and try to prove that $f(x)=0$ (mod m) for all $x \in \{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$. If $gcd(x,m)=1$, then we can find a prime $p=g_q$ (mod q) for all prime powers $q|m$ and $g_q$ being a primitive root mod q. Hence we can write $x=p^n$ (mod m) for some $n$ and we are done. If $gcd(x,m)>1$, we first observe that $t=0$(mod m) (by setting $x=q$ for $q$ a prime power dividing $m$) and repeat the argument for $m'=\frac{m}{gcd(m,x)}$.

Comment: Could you please explain why "we can find a prime ..."? Thank you.

Comment: By Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions. since the congruences $g_q$ (mod q) can be combined into $r$ (mod m), where $gcd(r,m)=1$.

Comment: I missed that powers of 2 do not have a primitive root.